# Will upgrade of iOS delete any of my videos or photos?

Tags: backup, upgrade, photos, ios

I wanna upgrade to the latest iOS 5 and wonder if my existing photos and videos at Camera Roll will be still on device. Is that right? Or I have to backup them before upgrading? If so, how would I do that - iTunes doesn't seem to backup those things at sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photos and videos in Camera Roll are not synced with iTunes - they are, instead, the "raw" photos meant to be synced to the photo-organization tool you use - whether that's a set of folders in your filesystem, or iPhoto.

In other words, when your iPhone is mounted as a "USB camera" (on Windows) or when iPhoto opens (when plugging it into your Mac), the contents of the Camera Roll are what you see.

That being said, iOS 5 **will** delete all of this data during the upgrade, so you *absolutely should* back them up before going forward! Assuming you're using a Mac, plug in the phone, open iPhoto, and import everything before doing the upgrade.

(And I recommend making a backup of your phone, transferring purchases, and then syncing everything you can with iTunes before going forward... the iOS 5 upgrade appears to be a *very destructive* procedure.)

Answer (score 3):

The photos aren't synced but definitively are backup by iTunes.

I just upgraded to iOS 5 and my photos are still at my camera roll

Answer (score 1):

You run the risk of losing your pictures if you don't have the "Sync Photos" switch turned on in iTunes.  The iOS 5 upgrade may completely wipe your iPad/iPhone so you have to do a resync to bring everything back.  But that will only work if you've already backed it up and have sync turned on.

Be safe, not sorry.